# Aligning bullet and text in itemize

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize, enumitem

I want to make the bullets in itemize to align at 0 mm (no indent). Using the `enumitem` package, this can be done by specifying the option `[leftmargin=*]`. At the same time, I would like the texts to align at 3 mm. How to do this? (I want to set this globally.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use as value for `labelsep` the result of `3mm` minus the width of a `\textbullet`; in the example below the last line is a "fake" item with a `3mm` wide rule just to have a visual guide:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\textbullet}
\addtolength\mylen{-3mm}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelsep=-\mylen]
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{itemize}

\noindent\rule{3mm}{1pt}Fourth item?

\end{document}
```

Of course, as **Mico** comments, these settings can be made global using something like

[image]

As **Mico** comments, these settings can be made global, using `\setlist`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\textbullet}
\addtolength\mylen{-3mm}
\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=*,labelsep=-\mylen}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{itemize}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to align correctly. I need 3mm from the left margin, not from the bullet.

Comment: You may want to mention how this setup may be made *global*, e.g., via a `\setlist{...}` instruction.

Comment: @guest you should have mentioned this initially. Anyway, the solution is easy. In a few seconds  I'll give it.

Comment: @guest please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Mico yes, good suggestion. I have incorporated it to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Can this definitely not be achieved strictly by the options in the square brackets? without needing the extra length?

Comment: You should remove the first "Of course, as Mico comments, these settings can be made global using something like"